# What are the journals of contemporary graphic design?

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

Are there any internationally recognized journals on contemporary graphic design? For example, where can I find critiques, reviews, and argued opinions of designers like David Carson or Uwe Loesch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are quite a few journals indexed in the [Design and Applied Arts Index (DAAI)](http://www.csa.com/factsheets/daai-set-c.php) which can be accessed through ProQuest.

[*Eye*, the International Review of Graphic Design](http://www.eyemagazine.com/home.php) is one other journal.

Gemser, et al. (2011) have surveyed the top *industrial design* journals by popularity and average ranking. They are not specifically dedicated to graphic design, but many sub-fields of "design" are interdisciplinary and you might find something there.

Otherwise you might try international magazines rather than journals.

Gemser, G, Bont, C de, Hekkert, P & Friedman, K 2011, 'Quality perceptions of design journals: The design scholars’ perspective', Design Studies, vol. 33, no. 1. www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0142694X1100069X